# ppm as hexane/propane/methane etc

Tags: organic-chemistry, concentration, units

This question is primarily related to stack testing data.

Whenever stack testing is being conducted and the parameter being measured is VOC concentration, it is often reported as ppm (as hexane) or ppm (as propane) and so on.  My question is: what exactly does it mean physically to say ppm as hexane vs. ppm as propane or heptane and so on?

My apologies if it's a stupid question.  I think my question probably gets into a little bit about how a flame ionization detector actually works.

Comment: ppm is parts per million.  So 1 mg in 1 kg is 1 ppm.  Also, 0.1 percent is 1000 ppm.

Comment: @DarrenRhodes not necessarily. If it were ppm by volume (which for gases is the same as per mole) it would be different, hence the need to specify whether the metric is mass/mass or vol/vol. And, in this case, the result might be normalised to a specific hydrocarbon, in which case it might be total voc mass/kg of gas.